# How can I get VS to consider my project dirty when (only) an .exe Content item is dirty?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, project, vcxproj

My C++ project includes a set of (non-code) files that need to be copied to the output directory verbatim. I added them to my .vcxproj as `Content` nodes with `CopyToOutputDirectory` set to `PreserveNewest`. For example:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="util.exe">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="lib_util_needs.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <!-- etc. -->
</ItemGroup>
```

This *almost* works; when I build the project, each content file is correctly copied to the output directory if its timestamp is newer than whatever's already there. *But*... if I update one of these content files without modifying an actual compiled code file at the same time, Visual Studio 2017 concludes that the project is already up to date, does not build, and does not copy the newer version of the content file to the output directory. Is there anything I can do about this? Things that do not work:

- Setting `PublishState` to `Prerequisite` under the `Content` node
- Listing content files as `DependentUpon` nodes under a code file's node

Edit: After further investigation, it appears that the behavior depends on the content file's extension. For example, dlls behave the way I want (project marked as dirty and built if the timestamp is updated), but exes do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get VS to consider my project dirty when (only) a Content item is dirty?

You can set the property the `UpToDateCheckInput` to the item:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <UpToDateCheckInput Include="util.exe">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </UpToDateCheckInput>
    <!-- etc. -->
</ItemGroup>
```

Or set the property `DisableFastUpToDateCheck` to true in the project file to disable `FastUpToDateCheck` for Visual Studio build manager:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>True</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Check [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties) about DisableFastUpToDateCheck:

> A boolean value that applies to Visual Studio only. The Visual Studio
>   build manager uses a process called FastUpToDateCheck to determine
>   whether a project must be rebuilt to be up to date. This process is
>   faster than using MSBuild to determine this. Setting the
>   DisableFastUpToDateCheck property to true lets you bypass the Visual
>   Studio build manager and force it to use MSBuild to determine whether
>   the project is up to date

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using `UpToDateCheckInput` didn't quite do it (it did cause a build to be triggered after touching util.exe, but the build process would still conclude that everything was up to date and skip copying to the output), but `DisableFastUpToDateCheck` did the trick. It does mean that this project spams the build output with a bunch of "everything is up to date" messages during a normal build where everything really is up to date, but I think we can live with that.

Comment: This is a bit hacky, but I managed to get it all by: (1) Leaving the fast up-to-date check enabled, (2) changing util.exe from `Content` to `UpToDateCheckInput`, (3) Setting `CopyToOutputDirectory` to `Never` for util.exe, and (4) adding an `xcopy /d ` post-build event to copy util.exe to the output directory. For the dlls, everything just works by default and I don't have to jump through any of these hoops.